# I was reading this hacking - art of exploitation book and the below code seems to throw the following error

Tags: c, pointers, casting, segmentation-fault, warnings

### Error

```
pointer_types5.c: In function ‘main’:
pointer_types5.c:11:28: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   11 |         hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) char_array;
      |                            ^
pointer_types5.c:15:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   15 |             hacky_nonpointer, *((char *) hacky_nonpointer));
      |                                 ^
pointer_types5.c:19:28: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   19 |         hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) int_array;
      |                            ^
pointer_types5.c:23:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   23 |             hacky_nonpointer, *((int *) hacky_nonpointer));
      |
```

### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;

    char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    int int_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    unsigned int hacky_nonpointer;

    hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) char_array;

    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) { // iterate through the int array with the int_pointer
        printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the char '%c'\n",
            hacky_nonpointer, *((char *) hacky_nonpointer));
        hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(char);
    }

    hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) int_array;
    
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) { // iterate through the int array with the int_pointer
        printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the integer %d\n",
            hacky_nonpointer, *((int *) hacky_nonpointer));
        hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(int);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. These are warnings, not errors, 2. They are pretty clear - you assign a pointer to an unsigned int which is smaller, e.g. on 64bit systems a pointer is typically 8 bytes and unsigned int is only 4.

Answer (score 1):

The code is invalid and has undefined behavior.

For example an object of the type `unsigned int` in general can not store a value of a pointer type due to their different sizes as the first warning says.

In header `<stdint.h>` there are specially defined int types `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` designed to store values of pointers of the type `void *`.

Also the conversion specifier `%p`  is designed to output values of the pointer type `void *` not to output integers that again invokes undefined behavior.

You could change your program the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { N = 5 };
    char char_array[N] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    int int_array[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    uintptr_t hacky_nonpointer;

    hacky_nonpointer = ( uintptr_t )( void * )char_array;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    { // iterate through the int array with the int_pointer
        printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %" PRIuPTR ", which contains the char '%c'\n",
            hacky_nonpointer, *( char * )( void * )hacky_nonpointer );
        hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(char);
    }

    hacky_nonpointer = ( uintptr_t )( void * )int_array;
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    { // iterate through the int array with the int_pointer
        printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %" PRIuPTR ", which contains the integer %d\n",
            hacky_nonpointer, *( int * )( void * )hacky_nonpointer );
        hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(int);
    }
}
```

If you want to output values of the object `hacky_nonpointer` in hexadecimal then use macro `PRIxPTR` instead of the macro `PRIuPTR`.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer, really helped me to understand.
As you state over here
**For example an object of the type unsigned int in general can not store a value of a pointer type due to their different sizes as the first warning says. **

Wouldn't a converting int to long work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing all `unsigned int` into `unsigned long`.

Comment: This isn't really addressing the problem that OP is trying to cast an array (i.e. a pointer to the first element of an array) to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

probably you are using 64-bit system, if you assign to long long int instead of unsigned int as in example, you get the result.